# creating dynamic menu using json, Html, JS & css for mobile platforms

Tags: javascript, json, mobile, mobile-website

Am creating a dynamic menu from json object(downloaded from server) using html, js & css for mobile platforms without using libraries like JQuery

i read like "document.write should not be used in event handlers like onLoad() or onclick() . its better to use DOM"

plz give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Can you show what you have already? Do you know how to load content with Ajax? Do you just need to know how to get it into your website with DOM? What do you want the structure of your menu to be like?

Comment: just i need to know, how to get it into my website using DOM... JSON has the following list in json format                <ul> <li>file</li>  <li>options</li> </ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create elements in javascript using DOM by using the .createElement() method.

**Example:** Create a div for your menu and give it a css class name.

```
menudiv = document.createElement('div');
menudiv.className = 'menu';
```

Now you can plug your json data into it by creating other elements. For example if you would like to create a link using DOM.

```
link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'urlFromYourJsonData');
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Your Link Description'));
menudiv.appendChild(link);
```

and so on ...

I suggest you have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement and make your way from there.

Edit: After seeing your second comment I also suggest you have a look at http://json.org to look up what JSON is. If you want to copy HTML code into your page you should use the `innerHTML` attribute.

Example:

```
div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'menu';
div.innerHTML = yourAjaxResponseHere;
```